# iPad 2 locked by Apple?

Tags: ipad, unlock

A relative of mine got an iPad about a year ago and has not updated it until November after he asked me to help him with the update. We had updated it to the most recent iOS possible at that time using his apple account. Later, after the update was completed, he asked me to show him the iCloud. I logged in using my Apple ID to show him exactly what it is and now apparently his iPad is locked for 90 days. Has anyone heard  of anything similar? Is there a fix?

Comment: I haven't heard of anything like that..

Comment: apparently one oh his it friends said that they lock it against illegal sharing of itunes content...

Comment: i have only spoken to him on the phone, i dont have any screenshots at the time. sorry :( Thank you for your help anyways! i appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is associated with automatic downloads and/or iTunes Match. See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4627

> Once a device or computer is associated with your Apple ID, you cannot associate that device or computer with another Apple ID for 90 days.

This article makes it sound like you can only sign in with a different account every 90 days, but this doesn't seem to be the case in my experience. I regularly sign into different accounts on our family's iPad when downloading apps and this has never been a problem.

I've only gotten warnings regarding this 90-day lockout when enabling iTunes Match.

The article also notes that:

> Note: Removing a device from your Apple ID does not override the 90 day timer. The timer must complete 90 days from the day the device was associated before it can be associated to another Apple ID.

It looks like you'll have to contact Apple if you want to have the device reset.

Comment: This sounds like a possible solution... Perhaps someone else tinkered with it and locked it and the relative isn't exactly honest... We will wait another 80 days and go from there! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In order that I would try:

1. Contact Apple directly to get them to reset your account.
2. Create a new Apple ID and restore the iPad to factory settings.

Comment: i'll attempt Chris A's solution but will definitely keep your in mind! Thank you so much for your help!